# How to update existing share folder attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, com, wmi

I want to change "Enable access based enumeration", "allowing cache of share" and "encrypt data access" attributes on share folder using COM Api's or WMI's.

[image: Advance Share Configuration]

I was previously using `Win32_Share` to create share but this does not have properties to assign these attributes.
but then I came to know about '`MSFT_SmbShare`' class but I can see only `CreateShare` method. I was to enable/disable these flags on exiting share but not able to find any `UpdateShare` method.

[MSFT_SmbShare class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830471(v=vs.85).aspx)

Please suggest a way to toggle these flags on a share by any of COM API's or WMI's.

Answer (score 7):

To change these settings, you can use the [NetShareSetInfo function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525389.aspx) available in the Windows SDK with the level 1005.

All flags are defined here, but note the documentation does not exhibit the `SHI1005_FLAGS_ENCRYPT_DATA` (0x08000) which is indeed in the corresponding Windows header file LMERR.H.

Here is a sample that demonstrate how to use it in a C# console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // get flags of "myshare" share
        var flags = NetShareUtilities.Get1005Flags(null, "myshare");

        // add the "Require encryption" flag
        flags |= SHI1005_FLAGS.SHI1005_FLAGS_ENCRYPT_DATA;

        // save flags (you'll need to have admin rights for this)
        NetShareUtilities.Set1005Flags(null, "myshare", flags);
    }
}
```

Here is the NetShareUtilities class that uses P/Invoke to get to the Windows API:

```
public static class NetShareUtilities
{
    [DllImport("netapi32.dll")]
    private extern static int NetShareSetInfo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string servername, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string netname, int level, ref SHI1005_FLAGS buf, IntPtr parm_err);

    [DllImport("netapi32.dll")]
    private extern static int NetShareGetInfo([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string servername, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string netname, int level, out IntPtr bufptr);

    [DllImport("netapi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);

    public static SHI1005_FLAGS Get1005Flags(string serverName, string name)
    {
        IntPtr ptr;
        int err = NetShareGetInfo(serverName, name, 1005, out ptr);
        if (err != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(err);

        var flags = (SHI1005_FLAGS)Marshal.ReadInt32(ptr);
        NetApiBufferFree(ptr);
        return flags;
    }

    public static void Set1005Flags(string serverName, string name, SHI1005_FLAGS flags)
    {
        // note: you need to have enough rights to call this
        int err = NetShareSetInfo(serverName, name, 1005, ref flags, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (err != 0)
            throw new Win32Exception(err);
    }
}

[Flags]
public enum SHI1005_FLAGS
{
    // note: all values are taken from LMERR.H
    SHI1005_FLAGS_DFS = 0x0001,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_DFS_ROOT = 0x0002,

    // these 3 ones are not strict flags, you'll need to use a mask as specified in the official documentation
    CSC_CACHE_AUTO_REINT = 0x0010,
    CSC_CACHE_VDO = 0x0020,
    CSC_CACHE_NONE = 0x0030,

    SHI1005_FLAGS_RESTRICT_EXCLUSIVE_OPENS = 0x00100,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_FORCE_SHARED_DELETE = 0x00200,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_ALLOW_NAMESPACE_CACHING = 0x00400,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_ACCESS_BASED_DIRECTORY_ENUM = 0x00800,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_FORCE_LEVELII_OPLOCK = 0x01000,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_ENABLE_HASH = 0x02000,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_ENABLE_CA = 0x04000,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_ENCRYPT_DATA = 0x08000,
    SHI1005_FLAGS_RESERVED = 0x10000,
}
```

Comment: I will use this code and let you know. Thanks for help.

Comment: Thanks it worked. 
The new thing I came to know that MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb525404(v=vs.85).aspx) is missing following flags 
SHI1005_FLAGS_ENCRYPT_DATA = 0x08000,// Require encryption

SHI1005_FLAGS_RESERVED = 0x10000          // Reserved for internal use

Answer (score 1):

These values all seem to be properties on the `MSFT_SmbShare` class; specifically, `FolderEnumerationMode`, `CachingMode` and `EncryptData`.

After updating the values, use the `Put_` method to update.

Comment: I need some reference or code to update these three attributes on existing share from c#.